# Using checkdnsrr with CodeIgniter "Form validation"

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is there an easy and quick way to use `checkdnsrr` as part of the form validation process in my Controller? I want to check if a DNS-A record exists for a domain submitted by users. I did look in the documentation for something useful, however I couldn't find anything.

**This is my form validation as of now**

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('campaign_package', 'Valg av tjeneste', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('campaign_domain', 'Nettadresse', 'required');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well, i ended up making a solution myself after some reading around.**

This is extending the regular form validation library, so need to load anything. I just created a library called "MY_Form_validation.php" in the library folder (be sure to change the prefix according to your own configuration) and then used following bit of code.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

        function validate_dns($str) {
                $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('validate_dns', 'Domenet er ugyldig, utilgjengelig eller inneholder feilaktige DNS-innstillinger.');
                if(checkdnsrr($str, 'A'))
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

**And the validation**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('campaign_domain', 'Nettadresse', 'required|validate_dns');
```

Works like a charm.